# why is blender 2.76b not installing?

Tags: installation

Blender version of 2.70 and lower work just fine but now I want to be updated with the new improvements in Blender so I tried to install the Blender 2.76b. The installation process goes on just fine but when I run it, it shows:[image]

I don't know what's the problem. I checked out the requirement page in blender.org and I think my PC meets it. Here are some information on my GPU:

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this and how can I get 2.76b installed?

[image]

Comment: I get a similar message myself on 2.76b, no GPU currently with the laptop I have  at the moment, but no issues within Blender. Are you using the `.msi` or `.zip` version?

Comment: I downloaded the .msi 'cuz of low size.

Comment: @Timaroberts, how do you get to run it? Blender's not launching at all!

Comment: Just extract the.zip and run the.exe file. No need to install

Answer (score 1):

Just maybe .... you have to change your sound quality from
16bit 192000hz sound to 24bit 44100hz instead. Hope it helps.
Make sure to go through all your sound devices and set it
up appropriately.

[image]

[image]

Comment: does the sound affect that much?

Comment: no harm trying if it's solves the bug , you can set up your sound again after it starts to work. 192000hz looks like sound card setting to me ... so I am guessing could be a bug or something.

Comment: I don't know how that did it but it really stopped giving the error message as above. but it still doesn't install.

Comment: did you try the zip version instead of the exe installer?

Comment: Aren't they the same. Doesn't the zip also contain a .msi installer? I'm not sure

Comment: No they aren't exactly the same the zip version does not require any installation. Just drop the content into any folder and run.

Comment: Funny enough I checked my sound settings and that was it. Didn't cross my mind since I wasn't having issues myself.